# Conditionally disable textbox in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Its a quick question.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VIN, string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.VIN) ? new { @class = "required Vin" } : new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

I get the error that Type of expression can not be determined because there is no implicit conversion anonymous type #1 and anonymous type #2.

Is there a way to conditionally disable text box?

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't do set a property in the model on whether or not the textbox is enabled or disabled based on the VIN being NULL?

Comment: No sure how. I have a view model with a field       [Required(ErrorMessage = "VIN is required")]
[DisplayName("Please enter the vehicle's VIN number")]
public string VIN { get; set; }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VIN, string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.VIN) ? new { @class = "required Vin" } : (object)new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks! BTW google search bring this question on the top if you search "Type of expression can not be determined because there is no implicit conversion anonymous type #1 and anonymous type #2, mvc razor".

Comment: That object cast was what I was missing. Thanks for the help!